# Ethereum mining pool

Tags: mining, mining-pools, gpu, cloud-mining

Guys I want to build a **mining pool for ethereum** which is based on **GPU mining**.

I've searched alot but I couldn't find anything except **genoil**(*cpp-ethereum*) which supports GPU mining but the creation of pool or anything like that is not specified in it.

There is huge amount of mining pool available like **dwarfpool**, **ethminer**, **nanopool** e.t.c. I want to create the same pooling service as they are providing. Just let me know the basic start, i will get into deep my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean you have experience setting things up from scratch. You can build https://github.com/sammy007/open-ethereum-pool from source. It's straight-forward in terms of dependencies. There are good setup/build instructions included. Definitely works with both the Ethereum main net and Ethereum Classic; you'll want to run separate instances for each, though (it won't work properly on the chain that is shorter once you've connected the pool to both chains). Probably works with other Ethereum-based chains, but I've never tried it.

Comment: I need mining pool for GPU based rigs not for Cpu. Open ethereum pool is specifically for CPU mining.

Comment: There is no difference except perhaps the default difficulty. The Ethereum protocols have no way to distinguish which is which and the pool source certainly does not. GPU miners and cpu miners alike can use the getwork and stratum protocols.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for stratum server software. All mining rigs use stratum to interface with pooling software and Ethereum.

Here is a project that supports Ethereum: https://github.com/coinfoundry/Miningcore

The project's authors run pools and open sourced the backend. Miningcore has no graphical user interface but the REAME.md file is useful. I like using this project because you can benchmark your pools performance against the pools run by [Coinfoundry](https://coinfoundry.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should learn how to use **VPS(Virtual Private Servers)** and be educated in Linux Systems or skilled with the Windows Command Line. Using PuttY is also needed.

*I would recommend reading this guide:*

https://blockgen.net/setup-your-own-mining-pool/#Mining_Pool_Setup

Comment: I am working on linux system from last 3 years. I had set up multiple coin nodes BTC ,LTC , DASH etc. the link you have shared is not for ethereum mining its for all the altcoin that are the forks of bitcoin but my requirement is to create a mining pool for ethereum so do share relevant material if you have.

Comment: I know, the link is just a guideline to also set up your own desired crypto currency mining pool system. The example in the guide shows the altcoins but with further gather of information about ethereum data you can set it up in the same way, respectively.